# Does disjoint union care about multiplicity of the sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I have come across this definition of disjoint unions:

> A disjoint union of sets $A$ and $B$ is a union $A\sqcup B$ of disjoint copies of $A$ and $B$.

However, this leaves some ambiguity: What if we have $A\sqcup A$? The above definition suggests that this will have twice as many elements as $A$.

However, we must also be able to take disjoint unions of families of sets $\bigsqcup_{X\in\mathcal S} X$.

> For a family of sets $\mathcal S$, a disjoint union is a union of the disjoint copies of sets that occur in $\mathcal S$.

And like unions I expected that the definitions must coincide in this sense:
$$ \bigsqcup\{A, B\} = A\sqcup B $$

But this would mean that
$$ A = \bigsqcup\{A\} = \bigsqcup\{A, A\} = A\sqcup A\text. $$

However, this is *false* by the first definition, because in the first definition, the multiplicity creeps in, while in the second, it doesn't. (The equalities here are obviously up to bijections.)

Now, one can generalize the definition for arbitrary families via the first definition so that a set in the family is also assigned a "multiplicity". Then this will make the above anomaly go away.

Comment: Does the source define what "disjoint copies of $A$ and $B$" are?  According to the wikipedia page on "disjoint union", it is defined on ***indexed*** families of sets, so that the elements of the disjoint union are ordered pairs, with the second entry being the index. Even if any of the sets are the same, the indices will all be distinct.

Comment: My source is Aluffi's  "Algebra: Chapter 0". He takes any copies of the sets $A$ and $B$, fixing $A\sqcup B$ up to bijections.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. If $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,3\}$, what are the disjoint copies of $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest fix to your notation would be to take disjoint unions of *multisets*, not sets. (And because every set can be viewed as a multiset, we might abuse notation to talk about the disjoint union of a set.)

What you denoted $\sqcup \{A\}$ might be denoted better as a multiset, $\sqcup \langle A, 1 \rangle$ ("the disjoint union of one copy of $A$"), where I have made up the $\langle \rangle$ notation. This is not the same as your $\sqcup \{A, A\}$ which I might denote $\sqcup \langle A, 2\rangle$ ("the disjoint union of two copies of $A$"). And $\sqcup \langle A:1, B:1\rangle$ would be your $A \sqcup B$.

Comment: Oh! That's genius! So whereas one can take unions of families of set, the corresponding generalization is disjoint union of arbitrary multisets!

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as "genius" - you very nearly said it yourself at the end of your question!

Comment: Also to generalize it to the maximum extent so that infinite multiplicities are also allowed, I think we can do this: Have each set in $\mathcal S$ be assigned to a set which has the desired cardinality.

Comment: Yes, that's right.